# I have the Codeium Extension installed on my Intellij, the extension suggest code, but I am unable to accept with TAB key

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the Codeium Extension installed on my Intellij. The extension suggests code, but I am unable to accept with the TAB key.

[whe I hit tab key to accept it, it gives me a space instead of accepting the suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v7YL.png)

thank you.

I am looking for to accept the suggestions by using the tab key.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the shortcut keys through File -> Settings -> Keymap. Under Plugins section you'll find the Codeium actions